# How to stop VS Code to duplicate files? (FileName 2.css)

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

I'm using VSCode in Mac and usually, they **auto duplicate some file randomly**. I suspect that could be related to some git config or command. As you can see, this time the VisualStudio Code generated only 263 files with 2 at the end of the name, but sometimes this happens to 3,000 or 5,000 files.

Why does this happen?

**How can I stop it?**

```
Version: 1.46.1
Commit: cd9ea6488829f560dc949a8b2fb789f3cdc05f5d
Date: 2020-06-17T21:17:14.222Z (2 wks ago)
Electron: 7.3.1
Chrome: 78.0.3904.130
Node.js: 12.8.1
V8: 7.8.279.23-electron.0
OS: Darwin x64 19.5.0
```

[image]
[image]

This is my current activated extensions.

[image]

Comment: it is not default behavior. Disable all extensions and enable them one by one until you find the culprit. Is it some kind of file versioning that you use? Do you ever get a `3` or `4`?

Comment: Always 2 because I mark to discard all changes when this happens. I think this is related to git not to another extension. And this not happens every day. It happens randomly, so I can't stay without all extensions until happens again.

Comment: We can't really guess..

Answer (score 36, accepted):

After a lot of investigation due to files that randomly get:

- duplicated and suffixed by numbers
- deleted

I discovered that it was caused by *iCloud Drive*. It was configured by default to sync my user directory. Disabling iCloud Drive or configuring it appropriately (by excluding any project managed by git) should fix this issue.

---

In summary, add `.nosync` in the name of your root file to solve the problem.

Example: Your app folder name is `awesome-app`, change it for `awesome-app.nosync` and iCloud will not sync it.

Comment: OHHHH GOD, Thank you so much. I started to use `.nosync` at the end of the file name and this boring issue stopped.

Comment: awesome, I thought it was because of some virus from VSCode. Is there any way to config for icloud to opt-out folder that have .git? 

Answer (score 3):

This is **definitely** not caused by GIT itself. (GIT doesn't..create new files, unless someone tells him to.)

Two thoughts come to mind:

1. This kind of behavior is not normal in VScode. Perhaps it happens when using certain extensions? For example, the [Local History](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=xyz.local-history) extension occasionally generates extra files.
2. Looking at it this way, it almost looks like someone copy/pasted a folder into itself, and rather than overwrite files, it created new duplicates of every file. Is it possible that's what's happening?
3. An easy way to tell if GIT itself is at fault is simply use Notepad++ for a day or two, and see if the problem continues. If the problem goes away, then you know it's related directly to VScode.

Comment: It's not for all files, looks random but I guess that is a duplication about files that I fetch and rebase from remote repositories. But I do it multiple times a day, and just a few times on a week the duplication happens. I will have a look at the local history and try to create a pattern about when and why it's duplicating.

Comment: I did some tested and observed better. I'm not using Local History. I add on my question the extensions I'm using. Also, I still think that could have some relation to the git because the VSCode usually duplicates files that my colleagues or I worked recently. Looks like some type of colateral effect after quick/automated actions to save a backup. But I'm not sure what is.

Comment: @RafaelPerozin It's possible to run some automated actions each time GIT runs. Maybe check your scripts in /.git/hooks (If the folder exists.) to see if there are any automated scripts running that could cause the problem.

Comment: @RafaelPerozin You could also simply run `git status` *every* time you run a git command, and eventually one of the git commands you run will trigger the problem.

Comment: I know, but I'm also doing it because I can't run `git add` without check duplicated files before.

Answer (score 1):

**@Jarchii**'s `.nosync` answer is spot on.  *(I would upvote it but just joined SO today due to this specific problem and don't have enough rep yet)*.

I had this problem when I had my git repo in my iCloud Documents sync path and saw the same symptoms as the OP.  Here are some additional steps to preserve the original path in case you have tools/scripts/etc. that reach into your git repos with a full vs. relative path:

If your git root folder is, say, `GH`, then you can so this:

```
mv GH .GH.nosync
ln -s .GH.nosync GH
```

This renames the folder, which iCloud will dutifully forget exists, and then make a symlink to it so things using the original path still work.

Answer (score 0):

You can also exclude files from iCloud by adding .nosync to the file name